# Django braces - login and group required

Tags: django

Starting with the following view:

```
from braces.views import GroupRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin

class AddAttributeView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    group_required = "SchemaAdmin"
    ...
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. If the user is not logged in -> redirect the user to login page
2. If the user is logged in and has no permissions: throw 403

With the configuration above, the user is always redirected to the login page (even if he is logged in but simply not in the group)

On the other hand, if I set `raise_exception = True` , the application always throws a 403 , even if the user is not logged in.

Is there a possibility to achieve the above without setting `raise_exception = my_function` and implementing the whole logic in `my_function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The django-braces docs for the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/access.html#loginrequiredmixin) suggest you should set `raise_exception = True` so that an exception is raised for logged in users, and  `redirect_unauthenticated_users = True` so that unauthenticated users are redirected to the login page.

```
class AddAttributeView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    group_required = "SchemaAdmin"
    raise_exception = True
    redirect_unauthenticated_users = True
```

That doesn't seem to be working at the moment because of [this issue](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/issues/181). As a work around, I suggest writing a short callable for `raise_exception`.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def raise_unless_unauthenticated(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('login')
    # returning None means PermissionDenied will be raised
    return None

class AddAttributeView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    group_required = "SchemaAdmin"
    raise_exception = raise_unless_unauthenticated
```

Comment: Already tried that. The user always gets redirected to the login view in this case (even if he is authenticated)

Comment: Thanks to you I found the issue: https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/issues/181

Comment: I was just about to say it sounds like there might be a bug in braces. Well found!

Comment: I will wait for the fix and then accept your answer. so far I think, it has to work with my solution (setting `raise_exception` to function)

Comment: Setting raise_exception to a function sounds like a good work around. I've added a small example.